# Deleting large amounts of rows in SQL server 15

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, batch-processing

I'm trying to execute a batch delete, but I'm having trouble executing it due to not properly using clustered index. Clustered index consists of three fields(int, int, datetime2).

The table consists of four columns(PK[integer, integer, datetime2], decimal)

What I have tried so far is doing TOP(X) delete which in the end slows down alot and deleting by days (one batch is one day) which is also not a good solution. Below I have attached the "by day" deletion script.

```
DECLARE
    @ITERATION INT = 0
    , @TOTALROWS INT = 0
    , @MSG VARCHAR(500)
    , @STARTTIME DATETIME
    , @ENDTIME DATETIME
    , @StartValue DATETIME = (SELECT MIN(DateTimeValue) FROM TableX)
    , @EndValue date
    , @MaxValue date = '2022-04-12';

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW;

WHILE @StartValue < @MaxValue
BEGIN

    SET @EndValue = DATEADD(day, 1, @StartValue);

    SET @STARTTIME = GETDATE();

    DELETE FROM TableX WHERE DateTimeValue >= @StartValue AND DateTimeValue < @EndValue;

    SET @TOTALROWS=@TOTALROWS+@@ROWCOUNT;
    SET @ITERATION=@ITERATION+1;


    SET @ENDTIME = GETDATE();

    SET @MSG = 'Iteration: ' + CAST(@ITERATION AS VARCHAR) + ' Total deletes:' + CAST(@TOTALROWS AS VARCHAR) + '  >> ' + CAST(DATEDIFF(millisecond, @STARTTIME,@ENDTIME) AS VARCHAR);

    RAISERROR (@MSG, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT;

    SET @StartValue = @EndValue;

END;
```

Is there any way to use clustered index to my advantage here to speed up deletion?

Comment: What do you mean by "not properly using clustered index"? What would be the "proper" use? Have you considered partitioning the table?

Comment: I mean that I want the query to use the composite index. I haven't considered partitioning, but I will definetely look into it. Thanks for suggestion!

Comment: is the slowness causes by the lookup of datetimevalue, or is it the delete(maybe slow storage/wainting on tlog)? since your only filter is datetimevalue, do you have an index on that column? if not adding index may help depending on where your slowness is.

Comment: Take a look here a this link https://michaeljswart.com/2014/09/take-care-when-scripting-batches/ maybe you can adapt it to your needs

Comment: Are you saying that the clustered index isn't being used at all currently? Please provide the actual execution plan for your query.

Comment: Got it solved by using combination of two fields in where clause. Now it executes under 3 minutes which is pretty fast for 40 million rows of deletion.

Comment: Might be faster to create a new table with rows to keep and do a `ALTER TABLE SWITCH`

Comment: Welcome! Don't forget you can answer your own question; that will help those looking for unanswered questions to answer.